# As the state is updated in a computed property component does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I do not understand what i am doing wrong. I'm using Vuetify framework with nuxt.js on top of vue.js.

I wish that the navigation drawer's initial state to be open on the index page but close on the others. I can manage to have the desired result when i first load the page (if it's the index page the drawer is shown otherwise it's hidden), but when i change the page using the link in the drawer (nuxt js is using vue router in the background) the drawer preserves it's state.

I've made a quick middleware containing this:

```
export default ({store, route}) => {
  const mitem = store.state.menu.filter(item =>
                  item.to.indexOf(route.name) >= 0
                )[0]
  const title = mitem ? mitem.title : 'Home'

  store.commit('setPageTitle', title)
}
```

here's the store were are the state and mutations (the menu json file contains the entries with the following keys: `{ title, icon, to }`)

```
import menu from '~json/menu.json'

export const state = () => ({
  menu,
  drawer: true,
  pageTitle: undefined
})

export const mutations = {

  toggleDrawer: state => {
    state.drawer = !state.drawer
  },

  setPageTitle: (state, title) => {
    state.pageTitle = title
    state.drawer = title === 'Home'
    console.log(state.drawer)
  }
}
```

And here's the layout

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      persistent
      v-model="drawer"
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
          router
          v-for="(item, i) in menu"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar fixed>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.native.stop="toggleDrawer" />
      <v-toolbar-title>{{ pageTitle }}</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>
    <main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([ 'toggleDrawer' ])
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState([ 'menu', 'drawer', 'pageTitle' ])
  }
}

</script>
```

The `console.log` shows me that the state get updated, but as the `state.drawer` changes the component is not updated and the drawer remains present.

Any idea on what i'm doing wrong/how to tackle that issue?
Thanks in advance

Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-navigation-drawer` component by default watches for changes in **$route**. You can disable this functionality by adding the prop **disable-route-watcher**. Making this change will allow you to minutely control the state of the component.